# Forward stream a video via node.js

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming

Any suggestions on how to stream a video via forward proxy to HTML5 page. This video is currently been streamed to swf file on IE with flash support. Am looking for solution by which a node.js server can forward proxy a video stream to HTML5 page.

Answer (score 0):

Is your stream an RTMP stream?  There are a number of tools that can accept an RTMP stream and playback HTML5 video.  Twitch and Facebook live accept RTMP for playback.

If you want to embed on your page (not on Twitch or Facebook) - this is available with [api.video](https://api.video) - see a tutorial here: https://dev.to/api_video/video-live-streaming-in-just-5-easy-steps-2f0i